# NAS box mounted via CIFS - problem with permissions

Tags: permissions, samba

I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu, and have mounted a SMB share via a line in `rc.local`.

The share mounts correctly, and I can browse files freely, create new files, and then delete them without problems.

But when I try and rsync a directory onto the mounted share:

```
rsync -a --delete /MySource/ /SharedMountPoint/
```

I get lots of errors:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/SharedMountPoint/SomeDir": Operation not permitted (1)
```

and similar errors about being unable to create temp files.

All the files and directories on the share are listed with numeric uid/guid - which I suppose is reasonable, as they were originally created via a sync from a windows box.

I have no great need for access control - its just a box on a LAN that me and my family use as a dropbox - I'd basically just like anyone to be able to access it (provided they've done basic authentication).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When mounting, use `-o uid=youruid`.
Then, all files on that cifs share will be owned by you so that you can edit/remove them.
E.g.:

```
mount -o uid=1000 //nas/share /SharedMountPoint
```

You can find your numeric uid in `/etc/passwd`

```
grep `whoami` /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 3
```

or:

```
id -u `whoami`
```

Comment: Ahh - that did it. I did try setting the uid in the mount, but I thought it had to be the uid associated with the target files. Thanks